# Acceso dinámico a una API con node-fetch

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, fetch

Necesito obtener repetidamente un valor de una API que se actualiza muy rápidamente, pero el código que uso me devuelve siempre el mismo valor. Según entiendo la petición debería realizarse en cada vuelta del ciclo for. De hecho probé de dos maneras:

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=ETHBTC')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {console.log(data.price)});
}
```

y de la forma sincrónica:

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
var request = async () => {
var response = await fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice? 
symbol=ETHBTC');
var json = await response.json();
console.log(json.price);
}
for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){request();}, 3000);
}
```

pero lo que obtengo es siempre algo así sin importar cuanto tiempo asigne entre cada petición:

```
0.03244206
0.03244206
0.03244206
0.03244206
0.03244206
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

He utilizado la API de Binance desde NodeJS y encuentro que es más sencillo y fiable con [node-request](https://github.com/request/request) sería algo como:

```
const request = require('request');

request.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=ETHBTC", (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // ...;
    }
});
```

o la implementación con `await` como la estás realizando actualmente.

Por cierto, las responses de la API de Binance incluyen en los headers el conten type `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8` no es necesario el "pipe" para transformar la respuesta a JSON.

Comment: Buen dato pero sigo con el mismo problema...obtengo siempre el mismo valor